# Generate reproducible results using the set.seed function

Tags: r

If you want to generate 50 reproducible samples, should you use set.seed function in the first way or the second way?

```
set.seed(1000)
for(i in 1:50)
  sample(x,10)
```

or

```
for(i in 1:50)
  set.seed(1000)
  sample(x,10)
```

Comment: Have you tried running your example code? Try the second one and look at the results.

Comment: I don't think either "method" will have much promise. You are not storing the results anywhere, so only the last instance will be available. I suppose that means that the second one is preferable since it the only one where the result would be predictable.

Answer (score 0):

First way

the first sets a starting point for a series of pseudo random numbers to be used in the loop.

the second way sets the same starting point at each run of the loop and will give the same number giving the same result 1:50 times.

say set.seed(1000) gives a set of random numbers (1,2,3,4,5...,50)

then in the first example you will get a sample corresponding to 1,2,3....,50

but in the second example you will get a sample corresponding to 1,1,1....,1